# How can I find files where ctime and mtime differ?

Tags: shell, find-util

Sometimes, a site is hacked and the intruder hides the new or modified files, changing the file's date (mtime). Usually, they set it to a not recent date.

Using something like

```
find . -type f -ctime -3 -exec ls -ls {} \;
```

I can find files that have been changed or added in the last 3 days, also if the mtime was changed using `touch` or other tricks.

The problem is that often this produces a long list of files that have been changed by normal activities.

My idea is: If I can find files that have "strange" ctime - mtime, the monitoring is simpler. In my idea, if I can find files that have mtime > ctime or that have very different mtime and ctime, this simplifies greatly.

Is there some way to do this with `find`?

Comment: Add more relevant tags.

Comment: You many just want to store the results of your find into a database, and then just use SQL to report out.  That way you have a nice history too.

Comment: This question feels like it might be a better match for https://serverfault.com/

Comment: This is basically "how do I use find?", i.e. application support. I don't see how it is a programming question.

Comment: I am not interested to rewrite another aide or similar sw.   
I simpy need a fast solution for the explained porpouse.   
I read the find man pages and googled a bit but I haven't found a simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

list all files in the current dir where modify date (stat -c %Y) is different to change date (stat -c %Z )

`stat -c %n#%Y#%Z * | awk -F# '{if ($2 != $3) print $1}'`

and for those who don't want to understand before executing

`find . -type f -exec stat -c %n#%Y#%Z {} \; | awk -F# '{if ($2 != $3) print $1}'`

Comment: The question is: Is there some way to do this with find?